# Not showing what it need to shows

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to make a count of the lasts IDs created in the day and the lasts in the month using this code

```
$TodayAttacks = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `logs`
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '-1' DAY) AND
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP()")->fetchColumn(0);
$MonthAttack = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `logs`
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '-30' DAY) AND
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP()")->fetchColumn(0);
```

I put it on the html like always but later [foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2qk3.png)

It shows 0 and thats incorrect. The things that work good is to show the total and running ids.

```
    $RunningAttacks = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `logs` WHERE `time` + `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND `stopped` = 0")->fetchColumn(0);

    $TotalAttacks = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `logs`")->fetchColumn(0);
```

Both of this things work but the other ones to calculate in a day and in a month dont works, just it shows 0.
Here is how the IDs on the MySQL works
[foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXSwA.png)
I need help to fix the $TodayAttacks and $MonthAttack to calculate what they need to.

If someone knows how to fix this tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the DATE_SUB function you won't need negative numbers for your interval value.  To get the running count from yesterday until now:

```
$TodayAttacks = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `logs`
    WHERE `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))")->fetchColumn(0);
```

To get the count for the last 30 days, try:

```
$MonthAttack = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `logs`
    WHERE `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))")->fetchColumn(0);
```

An example of how this works is posted here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itLtCzJbPbWuCWcx3jLiMk/1

Comment: Still showhing 0 after updating the code [link](http://prntscr.com/ldgnkp)] . In the website it still shows 0 for month and day . Help xD

Comment: After looking at your data again I see that you're using unix timestamps to store dates.  Updated answer above to work with that table structure.  Checkout the fiddle link for examples of how to work with unix timestamps.